# How to Add Element Created in JavaScript File to HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting a create an element in the js file which will then be added to the html div where the game is

I am trying to make a createMine function that creates a new element with the style in .mine and then adds it the the html game div.

```js
var newMine = document.createElement("div");
newMine.classList.add(".mine");
document.getElementById("game").appendChild(newMine);
```

```css
.mine {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="game">
  <button id="startButton">Click To Start</button>
  <div id="gameElements">
    <div id="character">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is working properly except `newMine.classList.add(".mine");` should be `newMine.classList.add("mine");` (don't use the `.` when adding the class, its only purpose is to tell CSS that the following is a CSS class).

Comment: A small nit-pick. Using term "file" in the context of a running program is confusing. JS files are just text on a disk, they don't do anything. Just say "created by JS".

Comment: Also change inline to inline-block to be allowed to change height and width

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code is working properly except two problems:

1. `newMine.classList.add(".mine");` should be `newMine.classList.add("mine");` (don't use the `.` when adding the class, its only purpose is to tell CSS that the following is a CSS class).
2. Elements that have  `display: inline` don't accept `height` or `width`. Use `display: inline-block` instead.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var newMine = document.createElement("div");
newMine.classList.add("mine");
document.getElementById("game").appendChild(newMine);
```

```css
.mine{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="game">
    <button id="startButton">Click To Start</button>
    <div id="gameElements">
        <div id="character"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when using classlist, don't write a dot at the beginning to make it work.
and as @connexo said, use inline-block